# Ember Octane and JQuery

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-octane

For the past few weeks i've been playing with ember octane which in my opinion is awesome.
I've tried a few ember plugins in order to test which plugins are working currently with ember octane, some of them require jQuery to work.
So my question is: if it's possible to add jQuery to ember octane to make those plugins work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested it myself but it should be as easy as:

- Add `@ember/jquery` package as a dev dependency.
- Enable optional feature `jquery-integration`.

An optional feature could be enabled using Ember CLI by running `ember feature:enable some-feature` or by editing `config/optional-features.json` manually. You could find more information about optional features in [Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/optional-features/).

Comment: Hey @jelhan your solution is working also searched for jquery-integration on config folder and set that to true and is working perfectly.
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note from @jelhan's answer is that adding `@ember/jquery` will only allow you to use JQuery internally. It will not allow Ember addons to use JQuery. For the ember addons to use JQuery, you would need to request that the addon add `@ember/jquery` to their dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your response @mbeiswenger.
How do we add jquery as addon dependency?

Comment: To add it to your project, follow @jelhan's instructions. To add it to an ember addon that is causing deprecation errors, you will have to make a pull request for that particular project.